vba-Access Dialog boxes FInd existing and/or Get new filename
I am upgrading a database from Access 2010 to Office 365. The issue is that the code from the Access 97 Developer's Handbook by Litwin, Getz, and Gilbert (Sybex) Copyright 1997, which has been used since the database was first developed in Access 97 to obtain file and folder information, no longer works.
A little additional context: I retired from coding at least six years ago, so I am somewhat rusty and not up to date. However, I have been asked to upgrade the database as I am the only one who knows anything about how it operates from the code side.
My problem is that I need to recode so that a user can either select an existing database file or name a new one with one dialog box, as it used to work in Access 2010 and prior versions. If the file was previously created by the database, this name should appear in the dialog box, but the user should be able to overwrite it with a new name. In other words, the decision is the user's, not the coder's.
I have managed to recode the folder locator and file find sections using Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)  and Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker).
When I try to either name a new file or select an existing one with the same dialog box:
I have tried to use Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs), but if the file already exists this throws up the following: "dbfiles.accdb already exists. Do you wish to replace it".
If I use Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker) I cannot name a new file.
Option Compare Database

Option Explicit           ' Require variables to be declared before being used.
Option Compare Database   ' Use database order for string comparisons.

Declare PtrSafe Function GetOpenFileName Lib "comdlg32.dll" Alias _
    "GetOpenFileNameA" (pOpenfilename As OPENFILENAME) As Boolean
Declare PtrSafe Function GetSaveFileName Lib "comdlg32.dll" Alias _
    "GetSaveFileNameA" (pOpenfilename As OPENFILENAME) As Boolean

Type MSA_OPENFILENAME
    ' Filter string used for the Open dialog filters.
    ' Use MSA_CreateFilterString() to create this.
    ' Default = All Files, *.*
    strFilter As String
    ' Initial Filter to display.
    ' Default = 1.
    lngFilterIndex As Long
    ' Initial directory for the dialog to open in.
    ' Default = Current working directory.
    strInitialDir As String
    ' Initial file name to populate the dialog with.
    ' Default = "".
    strInitialFile As String
    strDialogTitle As String
    ' Default extension to append to file if user didn't specify one.
    ' Default = System Values (Open File, Save File).
    strDefaultExtension As String
    ' Flags (see constant list) to be used.
    ' Default = no flags.
    lngFlags As Long
    ' Full path of file picked.  When the File Open dialog box is
    ' presented, if the user picks a nonexistent file,
    ' only the text in the "File Name" box is returned.
    strFullPathReturned As String
    ' File name of file picked.
    strFileNameReturned As String
    ' Offset in full path (strFullPathReturned) where the file name
    ' (strFileNameReturned) begins.
    intFileOffset As Integer
    ' Offset in full path (strFullPathReturned) where the file extension begins.
    intFileExtension As Integer
End Type

Const ALLFILES = "All Files"

Type OPENFILENAME
    lStructSize As Long
    hwndOwner As Long
    hInstance As Long
    lpstrFilter As String
    lpstrCustomFilter As Long
    nMaxCustrFilter As Long
    nFilterIndex As Long
    lpstrFile As String
    nMaxFile As Long
    lpstrFileTitle As String
    nMaxFileTitle As Long
    lpstrInitialDir As String
    lpstrTitle As String
    Flags As Long
    nFileOffset As Integer
    nFileExtension As Integer
    lpstrDefExt As String
    lCustrData As Long
    lpfnHook As Long
    lpTemplateName As Long
End Type

Const OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT = &H200
Const OFN_CREATEPROMPT = &H2000
Const OFN_EXPLORER = &H80000
Const OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST = &H1000
Const OFN_HIDEREADONLY = &H4
Const OFN_NOCHANGEDIR = &H8
Const OFN_NODEREFERENCELINKS = &H100000
Const OFN_NONETWORKBUTTON = &H20000
Const OFN_NOREADONLYRETURN = &H8000
Const OFN_NOVALIDATE = &H100
Const OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT = &H2
Const OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST = &H800
Const OFN_READONLY = &H1
Const OFN_SHOWHELP = &H10

Public Function ExportDatabase()
Dim exportfiletemp As String
Dim DialogTitle As String, AppTitle As String
If export_file = "" Then export_dir = "C:\"
DialogTitle = "Locate and Select Database"
AppTitle = "Database Title"
export_file = FindLinkedDatabase(export_dir, DialogTitle, export_file)
ExportDatabase = export_file
    exportfiletemp = export_file
    export_dir = ""
    Do Until InStr(exportfiletemp, "\") = 0
        export_dir = export_dir & Left$(exportfiletemp, InStr(exportfiletemp, "\"))
        exportfiletemp = Mid$(exportfiletemp, InStr(exportfiletemp, "\") + 1)
    Loop
    export_file = exportfiletemp
End Function

Function FindLinkedDatabase(strSearchPath, DialogTitle As String, LinkedDb As String) As String
' Displays the Open dialog box for the user to locate
' the required database. Returns the full path to required database.
    
    Dim msaof As MSA_OPENFILENAME
    
    ' Set options for the dialog box.
    msaof.strDialogTitle = DialogTitle
    msaof.strInitialDir = strSearchPath
    msaof.strFilter = MSA_CreateFilterString("Databases", "*.accdb")
    msaof.strInitialFile = LinkedDb
    
    ' Call the Open dialog routine.
    MSA_GetOpenFileName msaof
    
    ' Return the path and file name.
    FindLinkedDatabase = Trim(msaof.strFullPathReturned)
    
End Function


Function MSA_CreateFilterString(ParamArray varFilt() As Variant) As String
' Creates a filter string from the passed in arguments.
' Returns "" if no argumentss are passed in.
' Expects an even number of argumentss (filter name, extension), but
' if an odd number is passed in, it appends "*.*".
    
    Dim strFilter As String
    Dim intRet As Integer
    Dim intNum As Integer

    intNum = UBound(varFilt)
    If (intNum <> -1) Then
        For intRet = 0 To intNum
            strFilter = strFilter & varFilt(intRet) & vbNullChar
        Next
        If intNum Mod 2 = 0 Then
            strFilter = strFilter & "*.*" & vbNullChar
        End If
        
        strFilter = strFilter & vbNullChar
    Else
        strFilter = ""
    End If

    MSA_CreateFilterString = strFilter
End Function

Private Function MSA_GetOpenFileName(msaof As MSA_OPENFILENAME) As Integer
' Opens the Open dialog.
    
    Dim of As OPENFILENAME
    Dim intRet As Integer

    MSAOF_to_OF msaof, of
    intRet = GetOpenFileName(of)
    If intRet Then
        OF_to_MSAOF of, msaof
    End If
    MSA_GetOpenFileName = intRet
End Function

Private Sub MSAOF_to_OF(msaof As MSA_OPENFILENAME, of As OPENFILENAME)
' This sub converts from the Microsoft Access structure to the Win32 structure.
    
    Dim strfile As String * 512

    ' Initialize some parts of the structure.
    of.hwndOwner = Application.hWndAccessApp
    of.hInstance = 0
    of.lpstrCustomFilter = 0
    of.nMaxCustrFilter = 0
    of.lpfnHook = 0
    of.lpTemplateName = 0
    of.lCustrData = 0
    
    If msaof.strFilter = "" Then
        of.lpstrFilter = MSA_CreateFilterString(ALLFILES)
    Else
        of.lpstrFilter = msaof.strFilter
    End If
    of.nFilterIndex = msaof.lngFilterIndex
    
    of.lpstrFile = msaof.strInitialFile _
        & String(512 - Len(msaof.strInitialFile), 0)
    of.nMaxFile = 511

    of.lpstrFileTitle = String(512, 0)
    of.nMaxFileTitle = 511

    of.lpstrTitle = msaof.strDialogTitle

    of.lpstrInitialDir = msaof.strInitialDir
    
    of.lpstrDefExt = msaof.strDefaultExtension

    of.Flags = msaof.lngFlags
    
    of.lStructSize = Len(of)
End Sub


Why doesn't it work? If it worked in Access 2010 don't see why it shouldn't in 365. Edit question to provide code and error encountered.

I do not have my copy of Litwin, Getz, and Gilbert to hand to see the code you are using! Please edit the code that is failing into the question and the error message and show where the error is.

How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

The problem occurs with the inret integer in the function MSA_GetOpenFileName in 2010 it returns1 in 365 it returns 0.  I think the function that is failing is MSAOF_to_OF

You need to adapt this code for 64-bit compatibility. Mainly, all Longs in Type OPENFILENAME that start with lp need to be type LongPointer

Maybe lpstrCustomFilter should not have str in name - for consistency. Can you explain this declaration Dim strfile As String * 512? I have never seen * 512. Office 365 installed as 64-bit version? Should Longs in Type MSA_OPENFILENAME also be LongPointer? MSAOF_to_OF is not a Function, it is a Sub. Seem to have provided code for everything but OF_to_MSAOF - presume it does opposite of MSAOF_to_OF and is not cause of issue. Info about error should be within question.

Seems to me, the prompt to overwrite a existing file is a good idea, is it not?
Other the this minor issue, then I would consider adopting the new file dialog.
You can use that 30 year old windows API - (but, ask what other software your company is using that is 30 years old? hum???). The issue is NOT using office 365, but that of using x64 bits vs x32 bits.
So, there is a x64 bit version of that API, but as you can see, it is a rather old approach, and I would consider accepting that "minor" nag prompt when a user chooses to overwrite a existing file - really not the end of the world.
However, there is a x64 bit version of that code here:
https://gpgonaccess.blogspot.com/2010/03/work-in-progress-and-64-bit-vba.html

The prompt to overwrite was not appropriate in that the user could select to export one or more tables to the first created database or different ones. This has been done using buttons for each table and the export was after finding the file name. Agree the database is archaic but was created as an interim solution but it worked and became "it aint' broke so don't fix".  I have recommended replacement for over 15 years but finally I think this is the last upgrade
Thank you everyone for your help

Ok, well, it is and it did break. As I stated, this is not due to using o365, but that of you changing your processor architecture and making the jump to x64 bit computing (a big deal and big change). However, as I stated, you are still free to use the older windows api, it just that you have to change it to work for x64 bit computing, or use the office x32 bit version.  So, you can continue to use the windows api, but you have to adopt a x64 bit version, or consider using o365 x32 bits. The default for years was x32 bits, but now office default installs default to x64 bits.

The x32 bit version of office is still available. Probably best to update the api call you have to x64 bit computing, and the link I provided should work just fine. In fact, if done correctly, then the code can work for both x32 bit versions of Access, and that of x64 bits. First version of office to have x64 bits was Office/Access 2010 (14 years ago). However, it's only been the last about 3 years that office installs now default to x64 bits and not x32. So, x32 bit office can be still used, it just not the default install anymore. So, update the API code and you be good for another 15 years.
